# How to check that a List contains only certain unrelated class types using junit's assertThat?

Tags: junit, matcher, hamcrest

Would appreciate some help with hamcrest and junit matchers... :)

I'm using junit-4.11.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar on Eclipse Kepler with sun's jdk 1.6.0_30.

I have a class that holds an instance of any unknown type like so:

```
class UnknownClassHolder {
    private Class<?> clazz;
    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    } 
    public void setClazz(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

clazz can be any class.

I want to my junit test to be something like this:

```
class UnknownClassHolderTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {

    ArrayList<UnknownClassHolder> list = new ArrayList<UnknownClassHolder>();

    UnknownClassHolder x = new UnknownClassHolder();
    //lets add an Integer
    x.setClazz(Integer.class);
    list.add(x);

    UnknownClassHolder y = new UnknownClassHolder();
    //lets add a vector
    y.setClazz(Vector.class);
    list.add(y);

    //now check that we added an Integer or a Vector using assertThat
    for (UnknownClassHolder u: list) {
        assertThat(u.getClazz(), anyOf(isA(Integer.class), isA(Vector.class))));
    }
}
}
```

Junit's assertThat doesn't like this. It doesn't compile due to Integer & Vector Types not being related to each other via sub/super classes:

```
The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ?>, AnyOf<Vector>)
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this other than:

```
assertThat(u.getClazz().getName(), either(is(Integer.class.getName())).or(is(Vector.class.getName())));
```

Is there a particular reason for using `Matcher<? super T>` rather than `Matcher<?>` in the `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(...)` method?

Thanks.

Comment: Should that lone `Collection.class` be `Integer.class`?

Comment: Yes, its a typo. Either way it should still compile... I've fixed it in the original.

Comment: No worries, I thought perhaps the trouble was that `Collection` and `Vector` don't have a common superclass, but the problem is `<? super T>` as you surmised. I did get it to work, however.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using `is` instead of `isA` since you're asserting that one class equals another. `isA` is for testing that an object is an instance of some class. Second, the only thing I can make work is forcing the compiler to see these as raw `Object`s.

```
assertThat(u.getClazz(), anyOf(is((Object) Integer.class), is((Object) Vector.class)));
```

Comment: David, thanks for your response. however, your solution doesn't solve my problem, since your test will pass in all cases. The test should pass only if the list has an `Integer` or a `Vector`. It should fail if, say it has a `String`

Comment: @hs76 The assertion correctly fails for a list containing a `String` when I plug my assertion into your code. Did you test it?